# dell R730xd disk size less then total disk size after raid 0

Tags: raid, dell

On my R730xd, I have 6x1TB and 20x 300GB HDDs. That should give me about 12TB. But after I do the raid setup I am left with a 6.8 TB disk? I am doing raid 0 because I don't plan on storing anything critical on there but shouldn't I get at least a bit more space out of it? I expect to lose some due to the paritioning but to lose over half?

raid controller is as follows:

- 1x 300GB disk raid 0
- 6x1TB + 19x300GB raid 0

Raid setup here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao5zy.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "pure" RAID mode, the smallest disk commands the maximum space that can be used *for each disk*. In other words, by mixing your 25 disks, you have a total of 25*300 GB == 7500 GB == 6985 GiB which, after some overhead, become 6971.87 GiB.

> I don't plan on storing anything critical on there

"Anything critical" does *not* qualify for such extremely dataloss-prone setup. Please do not store here anything remotely valuable. *Consider any data stored here already lost*, so use it only for scratchpad / test data.

Comment: yeah the data there is already considered lost. hmm so i should split them into muiltple groups? one for the 300GB and oen for the 1TB?

Comment: @D.Zou exactly, split them in multiple group (based on disk capacity) and then treat them as you like inside your OS (ie: use as different block devices, as a concatenated one, RAID them, etc).